# MVVM. Set data in ViewModel

Tags: android, android-mvvm

It is necessary to put the data in LiveData to send to the callback. In this method:

```
    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
    this.currentData.setValue((Data) data);
}
```

according to the documentation setValue is called by MutableLiveData, I replaced the LiveData in ViewModel with MutableLiveData, but anyway, when I open the required fragment, the application crashes

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
at avocado.droid.ptitsami.room.DataViewModel.<init>(DataViewModel.java:24)
at avocado.droid.ptitsami.room.DataViewModel$ModelFactory.create(DataViewModel.java:54)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$FactoryWrapper.create(ViewModelProvider.java:268)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:179)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:147)
at avocado.droid.ptitsami.fragment.DataFragment.onCreateView(DataFragment.java:57)
```

How to fix it?

ViewModel

```
    public class DataViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
MutableLiveData<Data> currentData;
DataRepository repository;


public DataViewModel(@NonNull Application application, final int verseId) {
    super(application);
    int verseId1 = verseId;
    repository = new DataRepository(application);
    currentData = (MutableLiveData<Data>) repository.getById(verseId);
}

public LiveData<Data> getById() {
    return currentData;
}

public void setData(List<Data> data) {
    this.currentData.setValue((Data) data);
}


public static class ModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

    @NonNull
    private final Application application;
    private final int dataId;
    private final DataRepository repository;

    public ModelFactory(@NonNull Application application, int id) {
        super();
        this.application = application;
        this.dataId = id;
        repository = new DataRepository(application);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass == DataViewModel.class) {
            return (T) new DataViewModel(application, dataId);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
   public class DataFragment extends Fragment {
private int dataId;
private static final String KEY_DATA_ID = "KEY_DATA_ID";
public TextView tvTitle;

public DataFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootViewRead = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = rootViewRead.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    tvTitle = (TextView) rootViewRead.findViewById(R.id.text);

    DataViewModel.ModelFactory factory = new DataViewModel.ModelFactory(
            getActivity().getApplication(), getArguments().getInt(KEY_DATA_ID));

    final DataViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
            .get(DataViewModel.class);
    model.getById().observe(this, new Observer<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Data data) {
           model.setData((List<Data>) data);

        }
    });

    return rootViewRead;
}

public static DataFragment forData(int dataId) {
    DataFragment fragment = new DataFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(KEY_DATA_ID, dataId);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

repository

```
    public class DataRepository {
private DatabaseCopier db;

DataRepository(Application application) {
    db = DatabaseCopier.getInstance(application);
}

LiveData<Data> getById(int id) {
    return db.getDatabase().dataDao().getById(id);
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set the data on the ViewModel? Usually in `onChange` you put the data into views or adapters. LiveData is used to send data from your backend, repository, to your frontend, fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding source to `currentData` and change `currentData` from MutableLivaData to MediatorLiveData.

```
 LiveData<Data> data = repository.getById(verseId);
 currentData.addSource(data, observer);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things odd here..

In your ViewModel you have a getter and a setter for the LiveData:

```
public LiveData<Data> getById() {
    return currentData;
}
public void setData(List<Data> data) {
    this.currentData.setValue((Data) data);
}
```

And in your observer of the LiveData you call the setter of the LiveData??

```
model.getById().observe(this, new Observer<Data>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Data data) {
       model.setData((List<Data>) data);

    }
});
```

That does not make sense! When the `observe` method is called, the model already has this data set! So you do not need to call `setData`. Without the main issue, this will create an endless loop!

**Now to your main Issue:**

`androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData`

Room data can only be loaded to LiveData. The reason is because Room always keeps a link to it and automatically updates it, once the content of the database changed! But therefore YOU cannot change the content of the LiveData!

So please explain why

> It is necessary to put the data in LiveData to send to the callback.

You have to change:

```
//MutableLiveData<Data> currentData;
LiveData<Data> currentData;
```

and

```
model.getById().observe(this, new Observer<Data>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Data data) {
       //model.setData((List<Data>) data); <- this creates an endless loop
       // do here what you want to do with the content of the data
       // if you need to pass it to the viewmodel, do it, but do not call `setValue`
    }
});
```

For specific usecases a MediatorLiveData might be reasonable, but for this you would have to explain in detail why above doesn't do the job for you.